# how to hide a dynamic data bind column after checking a condition in vue-table2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-tables-2

I used the `Vue-table2` component for tables. I want to hide a column in my table after checking the value of the `isAllowColorPlate`.If that value is False, I want to  hide the column called `Color.`Data bind using an API called `apiUrl` using `fields`.Please help me to hide the column.

vuetable :

```
            <vuetable
              :css="css.table"
              ref="vuetable"
              :api-url="apiUrl"
              http-method="post"
              :fields="fields"
              data-path="data"
              pagination-path="summary"
              @vuetable:pagination-data="onPaginationData"
              :append-params="moreParams"
              @vuetable:loading="onLoading"
              @vuetable:load-error="onLoadError"
              @vuetable:loaded="onLoaded"
              :sort-order="sortOrder"
              :per-page="perPage"
              track-by="ItemId"
            >
              <template slot="FoodCategoryName" scope="props">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <span v-html="props.rowData.FoodCategoryName"></span>
                </div>
              </template>
              <template slot="ItemName" scope="props">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <span v-html="props.rowData.ItemName"></span>
                </div>
              </template>
              <template
                v-if="this.isAllowColorPlate == 'True'"
                slot="Color"
                scope="props"
              >
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <input type="Color" v-model="props.rowData.Color" disabled />
                </div>
              </template>
              <template slot="Status" scope="props">
                <div class="text-center">
                  <span
                    v-html="props.rowData.IsInActive ? 'Inactive' : 'Active'"
                  ></span>
                </div>
              </template>
              <template slot="action-edit" scope="props">
                <div class="text-center">
                  <i
                    class="fa fa-edit"
                    style="cursor: pointer"
                    @click="
                      onAction('edit-item', props.rowData, props.rowIndex)
                    "
                  ></i>
                </div>
              </template>
              <template slot="action-delete" scope="props">
                <div class="text-center">
                  <i
                    class="fa fa-trash-o"
                    style="cursor: pointer"
                    @click="
                      onAction('delete-item', props.rowData, props.rowIndex)
                    "
                  ></i>
                </div>
              </template>
            </vuetable>
```

Return values :

```
    return {
      isAllowColorPlate: "True",
      isLoading: false,
      recordCount: 0,
      apiUrl: this.$http.defaults.baseURL + "/api/xxxx/search",
      fields: [
        {
          name: VuetableFieldCheckbox,
          title: "checkbox",
          width: "30px",
          titleClass: "center aligned",
          dataClass: "center aligned",
        },
        {
          name: "FoodCategoryName",
          title: "Catagory Name",
          sortField: "FoodCategoryName",
        },
        {
          name: "ItemName",
          title: "Item Name",
          sortField: "ItemName",
        },
        {
          name: "Color",
          title: "Colour",
          sortField: "Color",
        },
        {
          name: "Status",
          title: "Status",
          sortField: "IsInActive",
          width: "10%",
        },
        {
          name: "action-edit",
          title: "Edit",
          width: "5%",
        },
        {
          name: "action-delete",
          title: "Delete",
          width: "5%",
        },
      ],
      sortOrder: [
        {
          field: "ItemName",
          direction: "asc",
        },
      ],
      filterText: "",
      perPage: 10,
      moreParams: {},
      css: {
        table: {
          tableClass: "table table-bordered",
          loadingClass: "loading",
          ascendingIcon: "glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up",
          descendingIcon: "glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down",
          handleIcon: "glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger",
        },
        pagination: {
          wrapperClass: "pagination float-right",
          activeClass: "active",
          disabledClass: "disabled",
          pageClass: "page-item",
          linkClass: "page-link",
          paginationClass: "pagination",
          paginationInfoClass: "float-left",
          dropdownClass: "form-control",
          icons: {
            first: "fa fa-chevron-left",
            prev: "fa fa-chevron-left",
            next: "fa fa-chevron-right",
            last: "fa fa-chevron-right",
          },
        },
      },
    };
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [vuetable2](https://www.vuetable.com/guide/), you can use the [visible prop](https://www.vuetable.com/guide/fields-definition.html#visible) to hide/show the fields. Like this-

```
let fields = [
  {
    name: 'name',
    sortField: 'name'
    visible: false,
  },
  {
    name: 'email',
    title: 'Email Address',
    visible: 4 == 4
  },
]
```

On another note, I would like to add a few things -

1. The **visible prop** accepts boolean values but I can see you are using "True/False" which is a string, so either use the boolean or make sure to provide the boolean by any logic.
2. If your fields are not modifiable, then it's better to make a computed property of fields so you can use data properties inside it for comparison (it would make code clearer) and that would be reactive too.

Now, as per your requirement, you can use the visible prop like this-

```
data() {
  return {
    isAllowColorPlate: "False",
  };
},

computed: {
  fields() {
    return [
      {
        name: "Color",
        title: "Colour",
        sortField: "Color",
        visible: this.isAllowColorPlate === "True",
      },
      {
        name: "FoodCategoryName",
        title: "Catagory Name",
        sortField: "FoodCategoryName",
      },
    ];
  },
},
```